# Datatables: Is it possible to use Ajax to fill 2 columns and use a different way for other columns?

Tags: php, ajax, datatable, datatables

I have a table with send mail info, I use Smarty, a PHP engine, to fill this table.

I want to add 2 other columns with open and click ratios (of the mailings). I use an API to get this information in PHP, but because the API is slow I first want to load the normal columns and then when it's loaded I want to load the other 2 columns, is this possible in any way?

Basically, Can I fill a data table with 5 columns and when that's done add 2 more with ajax?

Right now I use 1 ajax call to get everything.

Comment: Hi, i think that a lot of things are possible... by the way, which Datatable you use?

Comment: I use datatables 1.10.12

Comment: Vendor? Please remember that a lot of vendor do offer Datatables system...

Comment: I am not using vendor, I am using CDN, so just a script link <script>

Comment: It is possible indeed, but you should give an example of the table and what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have columns like Date and Subject, These columns are in my own database. But now I want to add 2 more columns with an Mail Api to see how many people opened and clicked

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely something you can do. I have had a lot of success using the columns option in creating and populating my table. I use a buildTable function where I pass the results of an AJAX call, the variable here is called dataList, and use the object to build the table as follows. In this example the value for data is the name of the field in the dataList variable whose value I would like to appear in the table. In your case I would expect dataList to be the results from your database.

Note that both the title and data fields can take functions or html as input so you could either make an AJAX call in this field, or input a placeholder div to append the results to later using JQuery or whatever you liked.

```
$("#table-main").DataTable({
        //options
        columns: [
            {
                data: "data1",
                title: "columnName"
            },
            {
                data: "data2",
                title: "columnName"

            },
            {
                data: "data3",
                title: "columnName"
            },
            {
                data: "<div id='ajax_result_holder'></div>",
                title: "columnName"
            },
            {
                data: function(row, type, set){
                      //make AJAX call, return result
                },
                title: "columnName"
            },
        ],
        data: dataList
});
```